# Tabuada em C# loop infinito

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo

Estou criando uma tabuada que faça a coleta de um número inserido pelo usuário e represente isso em forma de tabuada.

Exemplo:

O usuário colocou o número "20", o programa tem que gerar todas as tabuadas até o 20x20.

Começando do número 1, até a tabuada de 20. O que pode estar errado no meu código?

```
using System;

namespace Tabuada
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int multiplicando, multiplicador = 0, multiplicador2 = 0;     

            System.Console.WriteLine("Digite um número: ");
            multiplicando = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            

            while(multiplicador <= multiplicando)
            {
                
                System.Console.WriteLine($"##### TABUADA DE {multiplicando} #####");
                
                
                while(multiplicador2 <= multiplicando)
            {
                int produto = multiplicador * multiplicador2;
                System.Console.WriteLine($"{multiplicando} x {multiplicador2} = {produto}");
                multiplicador += +1;
                
            }

            multiplicador += +1;
            multiplicador2 = 0;           
            
            
            }
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu esqueceu de incrementar o segundo multiplicador2 dentro do segundo while, então como o mesmo nao é incrementado vai ficar preso nesse while para sempre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse código é bem confuso, o ideal seria até fazer com um `for`, seria mais curto e simples, e ajudaria não criar erros. Tem conceitos errados, mistura de variáveis. Um doa maiores problema é o multiplicador ser 0, quando multiplica por 0 dá 0, então não vai pra frente.

Eu nem melhorei muito (um detalhe importante é que tabuada vai só até 10, e completa deve ir até 10, então isso deveria ser validado, aproveitando o `if`), mas resolvi o problema da digitação errada quebrar a aplicação (pode tratar de jeito melhor), assim resolve:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        int multiplicador = 1, multiplicando = 1;     
        WriteLine("Digite um número: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var valor)) return;
        while (multiplicador <= valor) {
            WriteLine($"##### TABUADA DE {multiplicador} #####");
            while (multiplicando <= valor) {
                WriteLine($"{multiplicando} x {multiplicador} = {multiplicando * multiplicador}");
                multiplicando++;
            }
            multiplicador++;
            multiplicando = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3wdgat). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wm4Zas). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/MultiplicationTable.cs).

Comment: Perfeito amigo, no caso a linha if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var valor)) return; poderia ser trocada pelo int valor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); ?

Comment: Poderia, mas seria ruim para a aplicação.